# ActiveSupport::Concern and extending mongoid model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, mongoid, extending

I am using mongoid with rails 3 and have come lately to a very tough
problem and I need an advice.

I am working on a CMS and one of the ideas was that CMS would provide
some basic models definitions and end user would, if needed, extend
basic class with its own definitions and controls and save them in different collections (tables).

```
class DcPage
  include Mongoid::Document

  field a ....
  belongs_to b ....
  validates a ....
end

class MyPage < DcPage
  field c ....
  validates c ....
end
```

Up until last version of mongoid this worked (with little hack) and data
would be saved to my_pages collection. Because of some problem, mongoid no
longer support this behaviour and data always gets saved to dc_pages
collection.

When explaining my problem, mongoid team suggested that I use
ActiveSupport::Concern and provided me with an example. Which works
perfectly OK if extended class is defined in same source file. Which
btw. never happens in praxis.

```
module CommonBehaviour
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    field :subject, type: String, default: ''
    # ...
  end
end

class DcPage
  include Mongoid::Document
  include CommonBehaviour
end

class MyPage
  include Mongoid::Document
  include CommonBehaviour
end
```

So far I have found out that it works if I require basic source file in
my second file. Which looks like this:
require '/some/path/to/my/gem/app/models/dc_page.rb

Can you can see my pain now. Basic source file would of course be backed into
gem and therefor becomes a moving target.

Please help me with better solution.

by
TheR

Comment: Are you adding the common functionality directly to the gem source? Which class are you trying to alter?

Comment: I assume that CommonBehaviour modul and DcPage class are in the same source file ../app/models/dc_page.rb which is contained inside gem file.

MyPage class is defined inside current application as ../app/models/my_page.rb and it would extend DcPage class. In this scenario it includes CommonBehaviur module which is included in both classes.

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution to this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because this is the pattern for single table inheritance.
You would need to turn off table inheritance in order for this to work.

However, the suggestion from the mongoid devs is the correct route to go in this case.
It looks like you just need to require your module/classes correctly.